# change content of next td by using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table that in each row of that there is a combobox in a td tag, I want when combobox changed then content of next td changes

I wrote this code but it does not work:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table tr td').find('.combobox').change(function () {
        var myvar=$(this).val();
        $.post("./data.php", {
                    p_array : myvar,
                    }, function(data) {
                        $(this).parent().next('td').html(data);
                });
    });
});
```

table structure:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <select class="combobox">
            <option>
                  select something
            </option>
         </select>
      <td>
      <td>must be changed</td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in post is other thing than `this` before post... the simplest solution would be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table tr td').find('.combobox').change(function () {
        var myvar=$(this).val();
        var xthis = this;
        $.post("./data.php", {
                    p_array : myvar,
                    }, function(data) {
                        $(xthis).parent().next('td').html(data);
                });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use this you'll better cache it in a variable like Flash said.
Because this has another meaning, when it is in another scope.
Also you could better use closest with the element, so you're sure you have the next td refered.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table tr td').find('.combobox').change(function () {
        //cache it as soon as possible for performance reasons and readability
        var $this =$(this);
        var myVar = $this.val();
        $.post("./data.php", {
                    p_array : myvar,
                    }, function(data) {
                        $this.closest('td').next('td').html(data);
                });
    });
});
```